# Kwargs with method raises a TypeError

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

I've tried to use `**kwargs` in method arguments, here's my code:

```
class TextFormatter:
def format(self, text, **key_vals):
    injected_text = text
    return injected_text;



formatter = TextFormatter()
print(formatter.format("test", { "p1" : "t1", "p2" : "t2"}))
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
    print(formatter.format("test", { "p1" : "t1", "p2" : "t2"}))
  TypeError: format() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Do you know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

Your `TextFormatter.format` method takes three parameters:

1. `self`, which is a positional argument that is passed implicitly.
2. `text`, which is another positional argument.
3. `**key_vals`, which collects any extra keyword arguments.

This means that your method only accepts 2 positional arguments.  But you are giving it 3 (`self`, `"test"`, and the dictionary `{ "p1" : "t1", "p2" : "t2"}`).  Doing this raises a `TypeError`.

---

To fix the problem, you need to unpack the dictionary when you pass it using `**`:

```
print(formatter.format("test", **{ "p1" : "t1", "p2" : "t2"}))
```

Or, you could pass the keyword arguments directly:

```
print(formatter.format("test", p1="t1", p2="t2"))
```

Comment: While you are absolutely right, it might be noticeable that it would be more readable to call this as `print(formatter.format("test", p1="t1", p2="t2"))`.

Comment: Is there any other way to put key:value in method arguments? I mustn't invoke it like that **{"key":"value"} with astericks signs. I have to invoke like {"key":"value"}.

Comment: @flamaster09 - Well, then you could make `key_vals` a positional parameter:  `def format(self, text, key_vals):`